# Parse Json String into Kotlin Object throws InvalidDefinitionException with Jackson

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I got a Json String from an API and want to parse it into an Kotlin Object.

My Json:

```
{
  "Title": "The Secret Life of Walter Mitty",
  "Year": "2013",
  "Rated": "PG",
  "Released": "25 Dec 2013",
  "Runtime": "114 min",
  "Genre": "Adventure, Comedy, Drama",
  "Director": "Ben Stiller",
  "Writer": "Steve Conrad (screenplay by), Steve Conrad (screen story by), James Thurber (based on the short story by)",
  "Actors": "Ben Stiller, Kristen Wiig, Jon Daly, Kathryn Hahn",
  "Language": "English, Spanish, Icelandic",
  "Country": "USA, UK",
  "Awards": "5 wins & 18 nominations.",
  "Poster": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BODYwNDYxNDk1Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTAwMTk2MDE@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Ratings": [
    {
      "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
      "Value": "7.3/10"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
      "Value": "51%"
    },
    {
      "Source": "Metacritic",
      "Value": "54/100"
    }
  ],
  "Metascore": "54",
  "imdbRating": "7.3",
  "imdbVotes": "265,701",
  "imdbID": "tt0359950",
  "Type": "movie",
  "DVD": "15 Apr 2014",
  "BoxOffice": "${'$'}33,223,430",
  "Production": "20th Century Fox",
  "Website": "http://WalterMitty.com",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

My Kotlin Movie Object:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class Movie(

    var id: Long?,

    @JsonProperty("Title")
    var title: String,

    @JsonProperty("Released")
    var release: String,

    @JsonProperty("Runtime")
    var runtime: String,

    @JsonProperty("Genre")
    var genre: String,

    @JsonProperty("Director")
    var director: String,

    @JsonProperty("Actors")
    var actor: String,

    @JsonProperty("Plot")
    var description: String,

    @JsonProperty("Poster")
    var posterLink: String?,

    @JsonProperty("Metascore")
    var metaScoreRating: String
)
```

My Piece for parsing the Json into the Movie Object:

```
...
    var mapper = ObjectMapper()
    mapper.readValue(jsonFromAPI, Movie::class.java)
...
```

But when i run this Snippet, i got this Exception:

```
InvalidDefinitionException: Invalid type definition for type `model.Movie`: Argument #0 of constructor [constructor for model.Movie, annotations: [null]] has no property name annotation; must have name when multiple-parameter constructor annotated as Creator
```

But i don't know why.. Kotlin Data Class builds every Constructor so i dont have to declare a specific Constructor.. I guess there is something with the Id.

Comment: Because the first argument of your constructor (`Argument #0 of constructor`) has no `@JsonProperty` specifying the name of the JSON property for that argument (`has no property name annotation`)

Comment: But the Json does not contain a Id. The Id in this Object is the Primary Key in my Database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to make sure that you register the [jackson kotlin module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) which e.g. adds support for data classes.

> Module that adds support for serialization/deserialization of Kotlin
>   classes and data classes. Previously a default constructor must have
>   existed on the Kotlin object for Jackson to deserialize into the
>   object. With this module, single constructor classes can be used
>   automatically, and those with secondary constructors or static
>   factories are also supported.

With that you can create an `ObjectMapper` that already has this module registered using `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.ExtensionsKt#jacksonObjectMapper`. (Note how you can also use one of the extensions it provides to avoid stating the payload class)

```
var mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
val movie: Movie = mapper.readValue(payload)
```

As an alternative you can still create the object mapper and register the module using the usual API:

```
var mapper = ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(KotlinModule())
```

Comment: Hey Thanks!! I would never thought of it :D Both Solutions works for me

Answer (score 0):

Just add `@JsonIgnore` annotation to your `var id: Long?` property

Comment: I tried it, but the `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` does the same and it still throws the Exception..

Comment: Try to add default value for `id` ike this `var id: Long? = null`